# Change Player Position when a scene was change Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scene

So, I have this game that I created and there's a button that whenever I clicked the button the scene will change but my problem is whenever I click the scene button change it will go back from the start of the stage. I kind of want it for example in scene 1 I already moved into the middle of the stage, so when I click the button scene change, in scene 2 my player is already in the middle of the stage just exactly in the scene 1 and not go back to the start of the level.

Comment: Either set the position in an `Awake` function, or use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html

Comment: You need to save your object(s) location before the scene changes. After the new scene is loaded you need to read that position(s) and place your objects in your new scene (You can use PlayerPrefs for that). You can darken a scene when you're updating the position of the object(s) after new scene loading. (You can just disable the darkening effect after all object(s) are placed)

Answer (score 0):

This is something called State-Saving. In your case, you want to save only the position of the player. In the function you're calling to change scene, save the position as in:

```
public static vector3 TempPosition;
TempPosition = player.transform.position;
```

And reassign it to the player when the scene loads.

Comment: I cant use this because in my script that I used I didn't declare the player

Comment: Then make the player DontDestroyOnLoad as commented above.

Comment: I tried it but it doesnt work im sorry guys, or am I just bad at coding? I'm thinking of just implementing a checkpoint system, and I'll just make it invisible.

Comment: Not a bad idea. Keep track of the checkpoint the player had reached and move the player directly to that point after scene reload.